# Spring security login dynamically

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have a file bean:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/secured/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-processing-url="/login" login-page="/loginPage"
        username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
        default-target-url="/secured/mypage" authentication-failure-url="/loginPage?auth=fail" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutPage" />        
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="srccodes" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

I have a login page I check login password from extern database, the login is différent of "srccodes" password="password". How can I add user dynamycally and affect to him for example `ROLE_USER` ?

Comment: what is a question? Do You store user details in database ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/) 
According to your example you store password and users details in xml! It will get user credintals from database tabke 
1. you have to change setup of authentification manager

```
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
      users-by-username-query=
        "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
      authorities-by-username-query=
        "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

And setup connection to Database

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

2. if you want to create user you have to insert new record into

   `users` table and `user_roles` table